# Using Mainframe Datasets in Python3

Tags: python, mainframe, zos

Can some one please help me how i can update the mainframe PS file thru Python3 ? By using zosftplibi am able to connect and able to read the file , But my usecae is updating the mainframe file thru python code. Can some one please help me with syntax / sample example

Comment: Are you trying to use python on-platform or off?  Is it a file (in the USS file system) or a data set?  Do other things use the data?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear where you are trying to accomplish this (on or off platform).  A couple of pointers:

off-platform, consider the Zowe python SDK:
https://zowe-client-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/files/files_api.html

on-platform, consider z Open Automation Utilities:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKFYE_1.1.0/write_data_set.html